# How to replace the string using Powershell with condition text based

Tags: powershell

I have the following content in a txt file

```
This is the content of Project server
This is the absolute of Project server
This is not the content of Project server
This is not the absolute content of Project server
```

Now, I have to replace the Project server with Domain server on line No.1 alone using some condition of text instead of providing the line number?
The text file will definitely increase going forward and providing a line number would be a tough decision and looking for something like this where text = This is the content of Project server Replace ("Project server", "Domain server") and save the file

Replace ("Project server", "Domain server") will replace everything on the txt file, rather I'm looking to replace on line No.1 alone using select string pattern and replace

I've done the following, but it did not work

```
$string = Get-Content C:\Data\newfile.txt | Select-String -Pattern "This is the content of Project server"
$newContent = $string -replace("Project server", "Domain server")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's replacing everything is because you're setting `$string` to only the first line then I assume you're then writing `$string` back to the file with something like `Set-Content`. So you're only putting 1 line back into the file.

If you are sure that it's going to be on line 1 every time then you can do the following:

```
$string = Get-Content C:\Data\newfile.txt
$string[0] = $string[0] -replace("Project server", "Domain server")
$string | Set-Content -Path C:\Data\newfile.txt
```

Comment: It seems the code which you have shared does not write back to the txt file and save it.
Ideally, the updated txt file should look like this

This is the content of Domain server
This is the absolute of Project server
This is not the content of Project server
This is not the absolute content of Project server

Comment: @MohanReddy Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: Yes, now the script is working as expected. Thanks for that :)
Is there a way, where I can set the condition of text instead of providing the line number? In future the text file will definitely increase and providing a line number would be a tough decision
something like this
where text = This is the content of Project server
Replace ("Project server", "Domain server")

Comment: @MohanReddy requirements go into the question, not comments under an answer. Please edit it and provide all needed details.

Answer (score 0):

```
,((Get-Content C:\Data\newfile.txt)[0] -replace("Project server", "Domain server"))+(Get-Content C:\Data\newfile.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content C:\Data\newfile.txt
```